# Sending messages between users php

Tags: php, message

I am developing a website and in that users can send messages between users.

Which will be the best way to send messages.Some of them i knew are

1.Storing messages in database tables and displaying them.
2.Using a mail server to send mails instead of messages.

Which will be the fastest and most efficient? Are there any other ways?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want the users to be able to see messages on your site, you'll have to store it in a database.

Comment: @kennypu do u know how facebook manages messages

Comment: almost any type of storage that needs to be done for the web is done through some sort of database. You can technically store information in, for example, a file, but that is very insecure and inefficient.

Comment: if you get as big as facebook, others that work for you will fix whats needed. for now use a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can combine both methods.

1. Store messages in database tables, and display them when the receiver is online. Use some sort of caching (redis, memcached, ...) to help you speed up.
2. Send a daily (or weekly) digest of unread messages to your users, since they may not be online all the time.

Digest mails lead users to your site, which is helpful in most cases. Also, from my experience, sending too many emails is not easy to do it right.

btw, if you want real-time messaging, have a look at ejabberd

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: how does facebook manages messages?

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 I'm not sure, but mostly should be like what I said. However, facebook is pretty large scale, so I'm not able to imagine what techniques are needed for it at the time.